# Spring boot using test jars in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, hk2

Hello I have a spring boot application that runs fine from command line. However when I run it from the ide (intellij) it fails on every http request. The problem I'm having is that from the ide a test jar (scoped as test in maven) conflicts with the hk2 jar that I have in my app.

I can't exclude hk2 classes from the test jar as it is shaded.

Of course it also happens in my tests. So my question is how do I guarantee that spring boot loads only the production jars and not the test jars. I'm afraid that my Test might no be testing the correct binary.

Having integration tests that executes the compiled application is a solution however I would like to run it from the ide without recompiling the code every time.

The test jar is testcontainers postgres 1.1.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to trust `testcontainers' hk2 shaded classes`, then you could define 2 maven profiles, one for **production** and one for test which I called **hk2test**. The **production** profile (activated by default) includes hk2, while **hk2test** includes testcontainers. They are mutually exclusive.

**Define 2 maven profiles**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>unit test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>hk2test</name>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Activate the test profile in Intellij**

To use the profile from Intellj, go into the `Maven Project` view and select the `hk2test` profile.

**Activate the test profile from the command line**

```
$ mvn -Dhk2test test
```